# Dimension of the global sections of a twisted sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I want to calculate $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(\widetilde{L}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(n))(X)$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Here $L = \mathbb{C}[X_{0},X_{1}]/(X_{0}X_{1})$ and $X = \mathbb{P}^{1}_{\mathbb{C}}$ and we have a closed immersion $i:Y:=\text{Spec}(\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C})\rightarrow X$ such that $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}\cong \widetilde{L}$.

Then for $n=0$ we see that $\widetilde{L}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(0)\cong i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}$, and consequently we easily see that $\dim_{\mathbb{C}}(\widetilde{L}\otimes\mathcal{O}_{X}(0))(X) = 2$. For the other $n$ I struggle, since then you can't get rid of the tensors as what happened in this case.

Comment: Hint: the support of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ is discrete. What does that tell you about the relation between stalks and sections? Can you apply the same reasoning to the tensor product of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ with any other sheaf?

Comment: $\text{Supp}(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}) = \{x\in X\rvert (i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}),x\neq (0)\} = i(Z)$ (if I am right). Consequently we see that for every $x\in X-i(Z)$ there exists an open neigbhourhood $U$ of $x$ such that $(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y} )|_{U} = (0)$. I am not sure if I can extend this claim to $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y} $ being zero outside of $Z$. This is how far I can get.

Comment: How do you understand  "$i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$ being zero outside $Z$" if it's not as a consequence of $(i_*\mathcal{O}_Y)|_U=0$? Anyways, you haven't really engaged with the hint: you haven't said anything about the relation between stalks and sections for a sheaf on a discrete space.

Comment: I can't think of a relation between the stalks and sections for a sheaf on a discrete space specific. What I do know is that the global sections $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ on $Y$ generate the stalks $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$ as $\mathcal{O}_{Y,y}$-modules, but I don't know if this will be useful here.

Comment: I also tried to maybe find a relation by checking the natural map from $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}(X)\rightarrow \prod_{x\in X}(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}),x$, and then by the previous remark we have that $(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}),x = (0)$ for all $x\notin i(Z)$. But I couldn't substract any useful information from this.

Comment: If $X$ is a discrete space, this means that every point is it's own open neighborhood, and the value of a section on this neighborhood is the value in the stalk at that point. Now, you know that a section of a sheaf is the same as the data of a section on each element of an open cover, compatible on overlaps, right? Can you pick a convenient open cover of your discrete space to exploit these two facts?

Comment: I would say that you pick as open cover just the points itself (which are their own open neighborhood). Consequently you also don't have to worry about the overlaps, since they will be empty. But only $i(Z)$ is discrete and not $X$. So, to construct a global section on the whole of $X$ I think that we should take as open cover those points, and the intersection of their complements. Meaning that on this last open the restrictions of the sections will be zero by the fact that $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Y}$ is zero outside $Z$ ($i(Z)$ actually). Also again in this cover all the opens are disjoint.

Comment: At this point I think I've exhausted my capacity for hint-giving, and a full solution would be better. I have posted such an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can calculate the stalks of the tensor product as follows. As $Z$ is discrete, $i(Z)$ is too, so by the definition of the subspace topology we can find an open neighborhood of each point which intersects $Z$ only in that point. As the sheaf $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ is zero on the complement of $Z$, this tells us that the global sections of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ are just the direct product of the stalks: the sheaf property tells us that $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(X)$ is the equalizer of $\prod_j i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(U_j)\rightrightarrows \prod_{j,k} i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(U_j\cap U_k)$, and as the right term is zero, this gives our conclusion.

Note that in fact any sheaf on a space supported on a discrete set has the above description: it's global sections are just the product of it's stalks.  Next, since $(\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X} \mathcal{G})_x=\mathcal{F}_x\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}}\mathcal{G}_x$, we see that $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z\otimes\mathcal{F}$ is also supported on a discrete set for any $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathcal{F}$, because any stalk outside $i(Z)$ is zero. It now suffices to determine the stalks at each of the points of $i(Z)$.

As $\mathcal{O}_X(n)$ is locally free, every point has a neighborhood $U$ so that $\mathcal{O}_X(n)|_U\cong \mathcal{O}_U$. In particular, this means that $(\mathcal{O}_X(n))_x\cong\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for all points $x$. Thus we have the following isomorphisms of stalks: $$(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z\otimes_{\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_X(n))_x \cong (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} (\mathcal{O}_X(n))_x\cong (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \mathcal{O}_{X,x}\cong (i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_x$$ and so the global sections of $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z$ are the same for every value of $n$: a copy of $\Bbb C^2$.

Comment: At first thank you for your help. I have still one question which also is the reason why I didn't get the hints. We indeed find that $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}(X) = \prod_{j}i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}(U_{j})$. But why does this imply that $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}(X)= \prod_{x\in X}(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z})_{x}$? I don't see why the natural map from $i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z}(X)\rightarrow \prod_{x\in X}(i_{*}\mathcal{O}_{Z})_{x}$ becomes a surjection as well.

Comment: This is just the definition of $i_*$: we have $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(U_j)=\mathcal{O}_Z(i^{-1}(U_j))$, but $i^{-1}(U_j)$ is a single point $p$ by construction and thus $\mathcal{O}_Z(i^{-1}(U_j))=\mathcal{O}_{Z,p}$. But by a well-known property of closed immersions, $\mathcal{O}_{Z,p}=(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_p$, so $i_*\mathcal{O}_Z(U_j)=(i_*\mathcal{O}_Z)_p$. Our equalizer diagram tells us the global sections are just the product of the sections on each $U_j$, and this shows us that the sections on $U_j$ are precisely the stalk at the unique point of $Z$ inside $U_j$.